# Is there a convenient way to import bunch of modules (library) into Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a small "library" (which is, in real, just 8 modules) to use in my projects.
How should I import part of them when create new project? Just copy "lib" folder with modules inside and print:

```
from lib import mod1
from lib import mod2
...
from lib import mod8
```

Is there a more "proper" way? I've tried zipping modules in one `.pyz` file using `zipapp` module in Python 3.5, but `.pyz` files can't be imported. I also can't upload modules to PyPi because only I'm going to use it (very specific task).
I've read something about Python eggs, but can't say for sure, whether that's a solution or not.

Maybe someone knows more "pythonic" way?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can use `pip` to [install your package from source control](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/). That way you can host your library on your private git or svn or file share and list it in your package requirements the pythonic way instead of having to copy and paste it into each project that uses it.

As a side effect, you will also have an easy way to update it when you catch bugs and make enhancements.

Comment: So, I'll only need to do `pip uninstall` & `pip install` to update libs from remote storage in my project, right?

Comment: Btw, I've successfully downloaded my own module from Bitbucket, but PyCharm still can't find it (`import myproj` doesn't work) thought it sees `myproj` library as installed

Comment: Make sure that your library is installed correctly and has files in it. You can verify by importing myproj outside of pycharm. It could be because your setup.py isn't right

Comment: I had to install it with `-e` key.